# Calculated Measures - Beginning balance

Tags: sum, mdx

I am a newb when it comes to MDX so please bear with me as I try to explain this.

I have cube with a measure for cost `[Measure].[Cost]` and the query is setup with a time parameter to obtain the total cost up to that point in time.  @ToAcctDate and is used in the FROM statement as such:

`FROM (SELECT (STROSET(@ToAcctDate, CONSTRAINED)) ON COLUMNS`

but I would like to get the `PREVIOUSMEMBER` if possible and to something like

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[PriorPeriod] AS 
SUM( (STROSET(STROSET(@ToAcctDate, CONSTRAINED).PREVMEMBER), [Measures].[Cost])
```

so that I can then have both the YTD costs as of @ToAcctDate and the YTD Costs at the beginning of the period [Measures].[PriorPeriod] in the same query without unions.  is this possible?  and if so, is this the right approach?

Comment: hello
you won't be able to apply this to a set `.PREVMEMBER` - it is applied to a member and then moves back 1 but needs to know which member to move back from

Answer (score 0):

Maybe along the lines of this?

`HEAD` will find the first member of the set which you can then apply `PREVMEMBER` to:

```
SUM( 
   HEAD(STROSET(@ToAcctDate, CONSTRAINED)).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).PREVMEMBER)
 , [Measures].[Cost]
)
```